# Can't decrease the width of ListView.builder Item

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to decrease the width of each item from a ListView, and It simply won't obey... I know I can do it by adding some padding, but is there any other way??  I've tried BoxConstraints, Container.width, SizedBox,...

```
return ListView.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
    itemBuilder: (contenxt, index) {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 28),
        child: Container(
          width: 120, //Tried here...
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
              minWidth: 120, maxWidth: 120), //Tried here...
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: (currentCustomerId ==
                      snapshot.data?[index].id)
                  ? Border.all(
                      color: const Color.fromRGBO(
                          141, 195, 119, 1),
                      width: 3,
                    )
                  : null),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
            },
            child: Container(
              height: 116,
              width: 120,
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                 minWidth: 120, maxWidth: 120), //Tried here..
              color: Colors.black,
              child: Image.network(
                snapshot.data?[index].marina
                        ?.logoAppFile ??
                    '',
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
```

Comment: what is the parent of ListView, you can wrap the `Padding` with Align widget

Comment: I didn't want to place so much code but here's the order: Scaffold > Center > Padding ( top: 48, left: 28, right: 28) > Column > FutureBuilder > ListView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wrap the Padding widget with another widget, constraints goes down, size goes up on flutter

```dart
itemBuilder: (contenxt, index) {
  return Align( // you can provide alginment the one you like , it can 
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 28),
```

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [constraints](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints)